# Detecting Android low memory condition for per-app heap

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, android-memory

From Android docs, it appears that `onLowMemory` and `onTrimMemory` callbacks only start triggering when whole device is getting low on memory.

However, from what I understand, on Android, every app has limited per-app heap. Even if rest of the phone has plenty of memory, my app can gradually fill up its own heap with various caches and crash with `OutOfMemoryException` while `onTrimMemory` would never be called.

There are [ways to track memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android), but all of those are polling-based.

Is there a callback similar to `onTrimMemory` that also takes per-app into account?

Comment: AFAIK, no, sorry.